# On Win XP, Ubuntu One picks "wrong" homefolder

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, folder, windows-xp

I've installed UbuntuOne on a Win XP laptop connected to our company network. UbuntuOne doesn't let me sync folders on my local drive, but insists on me picking them from a network "home" folder which I don't use at all. Checking the settings, the UbuntuOne folder is however set  to "always in sync".

Am I just misunderstanding the error message? Since I came to understand that nothing outside the UbuntuOne folder can currently be synced on a Windows system, shouldn't the message rather be telling me about the restriction to that folder - instead of: *"You can only choose folders on U:\ "*?

Thanks for your help - I'm still a beginner with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One for Windows will only sync from your user's profile folder. We do have the intention of making it possible to sync from other folders.